# Raspbian - unable to locate package mysql-server-5.6 after adding repo

Tags: raspbian, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.6 in Raspbian 7 (wheezy).

I've added the repo:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.3.7-1debian7_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.3.7-1debian7_all.deb 
sudo apt-get update
```

When I type in `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server-5.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-server-5.6'

Only mysql-server-5.1 & mysql-server-5.5 are available.
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: did you run sudo apt-get update after adding the repo? Are you sure that 5.6 is available in the wheezy repos or do you need jessie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking on Raspbian 8 (jessie):

```
> apt-cache search mysql-server
mysql-server - MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
mysql-server-5.1 - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
mysql-server-5.5 - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
mysql-server-core-5.1 - MySQL database server binaries
mysql-server-core-5.5 - MySQL database server binaries
```

This is the same as wheezy (actually that's an upgraded to jessie system; if you have a new from scratch jessie 5.1 will not be there). So in fact 5.6 is not available. Note that Raspbian binaries are compiled for the ARMv6 platform -- you cannot use just any Debian package.  The current Raspbian (jessie) is parallel to the current Debian anyway.

## But

5.6 [is available for "stretch"](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mysql-server&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), the current Debian testing branch, and as Peter Green notes in a comment, it has at least [been built for Raspbian](http://buildd.raspbian.org/status/logs.php?pkg=mysql-5.6&arch=armhf).

Along the lines of [the methodology described here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26042/5538), you can *try* and install a stretch package on a jessie system.  I.e., add:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main
```

To `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Then run `apt-get update`.  Finally:

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

This requires various stretch dependencies and a few upgrades but is worth trying.

---

It also is in theory possible to upgrade the whole system now (from jessie) if you change `jessie` to `stretch` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, run `apt-get update` and then (this is the edge of the cliff...) `apt-get dist-upgrade` (which will probably take some time), but beware this has probably not been tested much by the masses yet.

---

If you have a Pi 2, 5.6 is available for pure ARMv7 distros -- primarily [Ubuntu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36383/5538) (it is probably an alternative in 14.04 LTS).  The default on [Fedora 21 ARM](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/27544/5538) is 5.6.26.

Comment: "although I notice 5.6 is available for "stretch", the Debian testing branch, but Raspbian is behind with that" according to http://buildd.raspbian.org/status/logs.php?pkg=mysql-5.6&arch=armhf our autobuilders built mysql 5.6 for raspbian stretch nearly a month ago.

Comment: @PeterGreen Good call; I've edited that in, but I don't know how anyone could actually get this -- do you have any idea?  If I add "testing", "staging", or "unstable" to a `sources.list` with "jessie", `apt-get update` then just says it cannot find an "entry...in Release File".   Also, it very possibly will depend on a stretch libc, at which point it becomes inviable (or at least, really really inadvisable -- switching distros is a better option if that is the case).

Comment: More or less the same thing is true for `sid` -- it hasn't been incorporated into the Raspbian repos.   While the libc version is [probably not an issue](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/mysql-server-5.6), the Debian armhf binaries are ARMv7 like Ubuntu.  You could try compiling it from the source package or upstream.

Comment: " If I add "testing", "staging", or "unstable" to a sources.list with "jessie", apt-get update then just says it cannot find an "entry...in Release File"." <-- I'm guessing you don't understand the format of sources.list

but I would agree installing strech packages on a wheezy system isn't sensible. The most sensible option if you really need 5.6 is probablly to build from source. or upgrade to stretch but that is likely to open a can of worms of it's own.

Comment: @PeterGreen No, I'm not a big apt user -- based on your clue I replaced `jessie` with `stretch` (since `sid` failed) and that worked, then `apt-cache` has 5.6.  I agree upgrading right now is a gamble, but I've edited in an explanation of how to do it (I think I've got that correct).  I may try it when I get a chance just to see what happens.

Comment: Actually you don't need to upgrade the whole shebang.  @cheezburger I've added a bit about installing the stretch 5.6 package in jessie (beginning "Along the lines of the methodology described here...").

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the repository in question only supports i386 and amd64.