# How to upgrade VSFTPD on Raspberry Pi to latest version?

Tags: raspbian

How can I upgrade my version of VSFTPD to the latest available?

```
vsftpd -version
vsftpd: version 2.3.5
```

I think there's a version 3.0.3 available, but it doesn't seem to get updated when I run my usual update command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it doesn't seem to get updated when I run my usual update command:
>
> `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y`

If that's your *usual* update command, you've been led astray somewhere.

- `apt-get update` will sync your local listings with the remote repos.
- `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade all installed packages to the latest version *in your local listings.*
- `apt-get dist-upgrade` is a prolonged process for updating the entire OS to the next version.  Chances are you've already done this and currently you are just going through the motions with this command now.  However, you may not have done it properly in the first place.  If `cat /etc/issue` says "Raspbian GNU/Linux 7" (and not "8"), you did it wrong and have never actually upgraded.<sup>1</sup>

If it *does* say 8, you should have vsftpd 3.0.2-17.

---

<sup>1. Which might be sort of my fault if you followed [the instructions here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26042/5538), since I didn't make it clear that you need to add a line to `sources.list` to both install jessie packages in wheezy *and* to upgrade from wheezy.  I've clarified that now and those instructions should work.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Yes it was "Raspbian GNU/Linux 7", so I'm following your instructions and currently upgrading my Pi and Pi v2. Incidentally the `sources.list` files didn't exist until I created them.

Answer (score 0):

Raspbian is based on Debian.

Debian generates three releases: stable, testing, unstable.

See https://www.debian.org/releases/

The "stable" distribution contains the latest officially released distribution of Debian.

The "testing" distribution contains packages that haven't been accepted into a "stable" release yet, but they are in the queue for that. The main advantage of using this distribution is that it has more recent versions of software.

The "unstable" distribution is where active development of Debian occurs. Generally, this distribution is run by developers and those who like to live on the edge.

Raspbian sort of tracks stable and testing.  It does not have the equivalent of unstable.

jessie is the current testing.  If jessie doesn't use the version you want you'll need to wait or build it from source.

Comment: Jessie is the current stable (or at least, if you download the latest Rasbian image, that's what it is, i.e., they're not distributing wheezy images any more).  I guess "stretch" would be the current testing, and it is available in the Raspbian repos (just [found that out yesterday](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37339/5538)), although I doubt too many people have tried upgrading to it completely.  You can try and install stretch packages on jessie, however (although in this case I think the stretch and jessie versions are almost identical).