# Unable to locate package nmap & sources.list error

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, apt, packages, source.list

Love to have [nmap](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nmap) on my #raspberrypi, but:

```bsh
root@qwers:/home/pi# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
root@qwers:/home/pi# apt-get install nmap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nmap
```

2. `apt-cache search nmap` has no result:
3. and `/etc/apt/sources.list: No such file or directory`

Went trough these steps without any result: [apt - "E: Unable to locate package update" when I try to update my system, why? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388541/e-unable-to-locate-package-update-when-i-try-to-update-my-system-why)

Ended up here to: [Apt "could not find a distribution template" error - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49040/apt-could-not-find-a-distribution-template-error#53465) with the result of:

```
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/stretch
```

Answer (score 0):

**Old question, but if anyone have the same problem, here is my solution:**

I had the same problem not being able to find the repositories on just one of my Raspberry Pis. The solution was to add the following to /etc/dhcpcd.conf

`static domain_name_servers=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8`

These are Google's DNS IPs but you can change them to any valid DNS

After rebooting everything is great.

Answer (score -2):

[Raspbian - unable to locate package mysql-server-5.6 after adding repo - Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/raspbian-unable-to-locate-package-mysql-server-5-6-after-adding-repo/37339#37339) led me to the solution after realized

1. the `/etc/apt/sources.list` was a broken symlink to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list`
2. solution: `cp /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list /etc/apt/sources.list`
3. then `deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main` added to the list
4. `apt-get update`
5. `apt-get install nmap`
6. Success

Comment: seems like the issue is that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file was missing/corrupt/compelte garbage ... changing that file to be the node source list is not really a solution - because now you have no way to update raspbian ... also, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` is not part of the standard raspbian distro. Clearly when you configured your system to access node repositories, you messed things up badly!

Comment: This is an absolutely horrible answer

Comment: raspbian updating well after this.. what can be the solution then @JaromandaX

Comment: Is it? You must have an odd setup in /etc/apt