# is ubuntu-on-pi2 able to run gqrx?

Tags: pi-2

all.  I'm a newly licensed ham radio operator without a radio. I bought the Adafruit SDR thinking it might be a cheap entry point. When it arrived, I tried to get the "FreqShow" gadget up, only to realize it would be a major project (for me) to try to make it work on the existing HDMI-connected display instead of the nifty small lcd display it was written for. 
so, it was off to find a nice "radio" GUI that would run with the gear on hand. Finally found "Gqrx", which sounded great but only runs on a Linux box - nuts - another brick wall! But wait! What's this about the new port of Ubuntu Linux that runs on the RPi 2B?

which brings us to my question: does anybody KNOW if this would all work? Being 70+, I'm getting a little weary of the "yet another chase through the maze" ritual - Raspbian works well enough, and, after a week or so of hacking my way through the SDR-on-the-Raspberry-Pi maze, it DOES run rtl_fm just fine...

Thanks large,
Clancy
KC3HIJ

Answer (score 1):

> only runs on a Linux box -- nuts

"Nuts" if you were planning on running Windows IoT, which would likely involve even more "chase through the maze". Probably 95%+ of Pis are GNU/Linux based; Raspbian is just a tweaked version of [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian).  I mention this in case there is any confusion.

So, you don't *need* to use Ubuntu, and to make life simpler you may want to stick with the most commonplace OS (Raspbian).  There are a [variety of Ubuntu variants for the Pi 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36383/5538), by the way (and possibly more since that list was updated).  I would stay away from "Snappy Core" as it is somewhat specialized and uses a read-only root filesystem.

In any case, regardless of what distro you choose, I don't see why this won't work.  Gqrz-SDR is Qt based and open source; it probably isn't that hard to compile if you want, but there's a binary package (v. 2.3.1), `gqrx-sdr` in the Raspbian repos and very likely most other distros as well.

Comment: Net, what goldilocks is saying is: do a `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gqrx-sdr` on your Raspberry Pi (assuming you're running Raspbian), and gqrx is up and running.

Comment: @PhilB. Just a touch of maze.  A sprinkling.  Wafer thin.  Down the hall, second red door on the left.

Comment: Phil,
Your step 1 went fine, nothing needed done. Step 2 looked optimistic as it prepared to go get Gqrx, but apparently couldn't find it - see below. I'm going to give up and write my own. Now, if I could just figure out how to edit, compile, and link my own radio code on this puppy...
result of Phil's step 2: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install Gqrx-sdr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Gqrx-sdr
pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Comment: Phil,
Your step 1 went fine, nothing needed done. Step 2 looked optimistic as it prepared to go get Gqrx, but apparently couldn't find it - see below. I'm going to give up and write my own. Now, if I could just figure out how to edit, compile, and link my own radio code on this puppy...
result of @Phil's step 2:
 pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install Gqrx-sdr
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Gqrx-sdr
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
Oh, well, it's just a boxful of transistors...

Comment: **Small G.**  `apt install gqrx-sdr`